# System call hooking example arguments are incorrect

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver, system-calls

I wrote an example of system call hooking from our Linux Kernel module.

Updated open system call in system call table to use my entry point instead of the default.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
char *sym_name = "sys_call_table";

typedef asmlinkage long (*sys_call_ptr_t)(const struct pt_regs *);
static sys_call_ptr_t *sys_call_table;
typedef asmlinkage long (*custom_open) (const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode);


custom_open old_open;

static asmlinkage long my_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)
{
    char user_msg[256];
    pr_info("%s\n",__func__);
    memset(user_msg, 0, sizeof(user_msg));
    long copied = strncpy_from_user(user_msg, filename, sizeof(user_msg));
    pr_info("copied:%ld\n", copied);
    pr_info("%s\n",user_msg);

    return old_open(filename, flags, mode);
}



static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    sys_call_table = (sys_call_ptr_t *)kallsyms_lookup_name(sym_name);
    old_open = (custom_open)sys_call_table[__NR_open];
    // Temporarily disable write protection
    write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000));
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (sys_call_ptr_t)my_open;
    // Re-enable write protection
    write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    // Temporarily disable write protection
    write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000));
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (sys_call_ptr_t)old_open;
    // Re-enable write protection
    write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000);

}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

I wrote a simple user program to verify.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = syscall(__NR_open, "hello.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0777);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

File gets created in my folder, but strncpy_user fails with bad address

```
[  927.415905] my_open
[  927.415906] copied:-14
```

What is the mistake in the above code?

Comment: Style: Why would you want to have a non-`const` / non-static global `char *sym_name`?  Also, `char user_msg[256] = {0}` would be easier than memset.  Also for a one-off experiment, I might have just assumed that the syscall table entry would be `sys_open`, instead of saving the old pointer.  (to a non-static variable for some reason.)

Comment: `-14` returned by `strncpy_from_user` is `-EFAULT`.  Are you sure your `syscall` wrapper is actually passing a pointer to a valid string?  Check with `strace`.

Comment: From strace: open("hello.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0777) = 3 . The file gets created successfully

Comment: Oh, also, you have a potential buffer overread bug: `strncpy` won't 0-terminate the destination if the source string is too large to fit.  Zeroing the buffer ahead of time is useless; instead you need to check for the return value being non-error and <= size.  Or just unconditionally `user_msg[sizeof(user_msg)-1] = 0` after strncpy to always zero the last byte after, and the first byte before copying.  Since it's small and on the stack, that's not even bad for performance.

Comment: You replace original function with one signature by your function with **different signature** and ask why you got wrong parameters? Really? Explicit cast to `(sys_call_ptr_t)` which you use for overcome compiler's warnings/errors is the direct signal of "something goes wrong".

Comment: Kernel version?

Comment: Linux Kernel version:5.2, architecture:x86_64

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OP is probably using a kernel/architecture that uses "syscall wrappers" where the system call table contains a wrapper function that calls the real syscall function (possibly as an inline function call). The x86_64 architecture has used syscall wrappers since kernel version 4.17.

For x86_64 on kernel 4.17 or later, `sys_call_table[__NR_open]` points to `__x64_sys_open` (with prototype `asmlinkage long __x64_sys_open(const struct pt_regs *regs)`), which calls `static` function `__se_sys_open` (with prototype `static long __se_sys_open(const __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)`), which calls inline function `__do_sys_open` (with prototype `static inline long __do_sys_open(const __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)`.  Those will all be defined by the `SYSCALL_DEFINE3(open, const char __user *, filename, int, flags, umode_t, mode)` macro call in "fs/open.c" and the function body that follows the macro call.

`SYSCALL_DEFINE3` is defined in "include/linux/syscalls.h" and uses the `SYSCALL_DEFINEx` macro in the same file, which uses the `__SYSCALL_DEFINEx` macro.  Since x86_64 defines `CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER`, the `__SYSCALL_DEFINEx` macro is defined by `#include <asm/syscall_wrapper.h>`, which maps to "arch/x86/include/asm/syscall_wrapper.h".

---

For background on this change, see

- LWN: [use struct pt_regs based syscall calling for x86-64](https://lwn.net/Articles/750536/)
- LKML: *[PATCH 000/109] remove in-kernel calls to syscalls* https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/29/409

It seems the motivation is to only pass a pointer to `pt_regs`, instead of having a bunch of user-space values in registers down the call chain.  (Perhaps to increase resistance to Spectre attacks by making gadgets less useful?)

---

**Why `open` still worked, even though the wrapper didn't**:

If OP is indeed using x86_64 kernel 4.17 or later, and replacing the `sys_call_table[__NR_open]` entry with a pointer to a function that uses a different prototype and calls the original function (pointed to by `old_open`) with the same parameters, that explains why the call to `strncpy_from_user(user_msg, filename, sizeof(user_msg))` failed. Although declared as `const char * __user filename`, the `filename` pointer is actually pointing to the original `struct pt_regs` in kernel space.

In the subsequent call to `old_open(filename, flags, mode)`, the first parameter `filename` is still pointing to the original `struct pt_regs` so the old function (which expects a single parameter of type `struct pt_regs *`) still works as expected.

i.e. the function passed on its first pointer arg unchanged, despite calling it a different type.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I clearly understood the mistake i made. So, what is the way to get the function parameters?

Comment: Can you please provide more information on who actually maps pt_regs to system call handler arguments

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Below is working code, Thanks everyone for providing inputs

```
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/kallsyms.h>

    MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
    char *sym_name = "sys_call_table";

    typedef asmlinkage long (*sys_call_ptr_t)(const struct pt_regs *);
    static sys_call_ptr_t *sys_call_table;


    sys_call_ptr_t old_open;

    static asmlinkage long my_open(const struct pt_regs *regs)
    {
        char __user *filename = (char *)regs->di;
            char user_filename[256] = {0};
        long copied = strncpy_from_user(user_filename, filename, sizeof(user_filename));
        if (copied > 0)
            pr_info("%s filename:%s\n",__func__, user_filename);
        return old_open(regs);
    }



    static int __init hello_init(void)
    {
        sys_call_table = (sys_call_ptr_t *)kallsyms_lookup_name(sym_name);
        old_open = sys_call_table[__NR_open];
        // Temporarily disable write protection
        write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000));
        sys_call_table[__NR_open] = my_open;
        // Re-enable write protection
        write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000);

        return 0;
    }

    static void __exit hello_exit(void)
    {
        // Temporarily disable write protection
        write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000));
        sys_call_table[__NR_open] = old_open;
        // Re-enable write protection
        write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000);

    }

    module_init(hello_init);
    module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Comment: Implementing the calling convention yourself (taking first arg from RDI) is a bit of a hack, but yeah that's probably easier than getting kernel macros to generate a wrapper for you.  You still expose the same bug of passing a possibly-unterminated buffer to a `%s` format string; maybe use `%.256s` to set a maximum.  It's pointless to `= {0}` init the whole array before passing its full size to `strncpy`; that's just wasted zeroing work.