# Error: conflicting types when trying to make a simple syscall

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm brand new to Linux programming and I'm trying to implement a simple system call loosely following this guide: https://medium.com/anubhav-shrimal/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-dad32875872. In my linux kernel directory, I created a new directory called `my_syscall`. Within that directory, I created `my_syscall.c`. Here is `my_syscall.c`

```
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

asmlinkage long sys_my_syscall(int i) {
   prink(KERN_INFO "This is the system call.");
   return(0);
}
```

I then created a `Makefile` in the `my_syscall` directory with a single line:

```
obj-y := my_syscall.o
```

I then edited this line in the `Makefile` in the kernel directory to be:

```
core-y         += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ my_syscall/
```

Then, in the directory `linux-5.4.15/arch/x86/entry/syscalls`, I edited the `syscall_64.tbl` to include the following line at the very end:

```
548     64         my_syscall          sys_my_syscall
```

Finally, in the directory `linux-5.4.15/include/linux`, I edited the `syscalls.h` file to include this line before the `#endif`:

```
asmlinkage long sys_my_syscall(int i);
```

Now, when I run the command `sudo make`, I run into the following error soon after:

```
./arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_64.h:2664:19: error: conflicting types for 'sys_my_syscall'
__SYSCALL_64(548, sys_my_syscall, )

arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.c:18:60: note: in definition of macro '__SYSCALL-64'
  #define __SYSCALL_64(nr, sym, qual) extern asmlinkage long sym(const struct pt_regs *);

In file included from arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.c:7:0:
./include/linux/syscalls.h:1423:17: note: previous declaration of 'sys_my_syscall' was here
 asmlinkage long sys_my_syscall(int i);
                 ^
make[3]: *** [arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/entry] Error 2
make[1]: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

I have no idea how to approach this error. With a conflicting types error, I would think I declared the syscall differently in someplace, but in both `my_syscall.c` and the `syscalls.h` files, the declaration is the same. These were the only two files where the syscall is declared, but it is also named within `syscall_64.tbl` and it seems like this is where linux is trying to point me towards. However, I don't see what's wrong with how I declared it in the table as I followed the guide directly. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Info:

Kernel version: 5.4.15

Linux Distribution: Ubuntu 14

Comment: Possible duplicate: [System call hooking example arguments are incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851520/system-call-hooking-example-arguments-are-incorrect). Since version 4.17 on x86_64 "original" syscalls functions accept **single** argument `const struct pt_regs *` which packs their real arguments.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't think this Q is a dupe of [System call hooking example arguments are incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851520/system-call-hooking-example-arguments-are-incorrect). This Q is about adding a _new_ syscall, not hooking an existing syscall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually gave up on trying to implement this in kernel 5. Unfortunately, none of the other solutions resulted in my kernel compiling. I rolled back my kernel and followed the steps [here](https://dev.to/omergulen/how-to-add-system-call-syscall-to-the-kernel-compile-and-test-it-3e6p). This resulted in the system call working correctly. I'm not sure how to make this function in kernel 5+.

Answer (score 6):

I just changed the location where the syscall number is defined in **syscall_64.tbl**.

Instead of this:

```
548     64         my_syscall          sys_my_syscall
```

I wrote this:

```
436     common     my_syscall          __x64_sys_my_syscall
```

[Screen Capture of my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IZd8.jpg)

It  worked out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something similar and got the exact same error.

What fixed the error for me is changing the last part of the syscall_64.tbl table entry from "sys_my_syscall" to "__x64_sys_my_syscall". If you scroll up, other entries have the same prefix. The kernel started compiling after I made that change.

Comment: I tried this before as well actually. The kernel compiled for a longer amount of time but eventually another error popped up

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <linux/syscalls.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>

    SYSCALL_DEFINE1(my_syscall, int, i)
    {
       printk(KERN_INFO "This is the system call (param %d).\n", i);
       return(0);
    }
```

For kernel 5, try deleting "sys_" before "my_syscall" and try. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Some architectures (including x86-64) use *syscall wrappers* to call the real syscall handler. To define the real syscall handler and its wrappers (for architectures that use syscall wrappers), use one of the `SYSCALL_DEFINE<n>` macros before the body of the syscall handler. The parameters of the `SYSCALL_DEFINE<n>` macros are the function name, followed by `<n>` pairs of ``*type*, *param*'' for the function parameters.

Your `sys_my_syscall` syscall handler function has one parameter, so use the `SYSCALL_DEFINE1` macro before the body of the function:

```
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

SYSCALL_DEFINE1(sys_my_syscall, int, i)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "This is the system call (param %d).\n", i);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but it resulted in the same error as before

Comment: Which `#endif` did you insert the `asmlinkage long sys_my_syscall(int i);` line before in "include/linux/syscalls.h"? It needs to be somewhere between the `#ifndef CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER` and the matching `#endif /* CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER */`.

Comment: This was probably my issue. I inserted the function before the very last `#endif` in the `syscalls.h` file