# linux kernal module hook delete_module and get the name

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am doing an exercise where I need to hide my kernel from `lsmod` but I can still remove it using `rmmod`. To do that I hook the delete module function and want to check the deleted module name
but I can't make it work.

`module_name` is always empty (even if I use `copy_from_user()`) but `name_len` always contains value that is greater than 0 (kernal version 5.19.0-40-generic)

```c
asmlinkage long delete_module_func(const char __user *name_user, unsigned int flags)
{
    long ret;
    char module_name[256];
    int name_len;
    struct module *mod;

    name_len = strncpy_from_user(module_name, name_user, sizeof(module_name));
    printk(KERN_INFO "name_len %d", name_len);
    if (name_len <= 0 ) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "failed");
        goto done;
    }

done:
    ret = orig_delete_module_func(name_user, flags);    
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: "but i can't make it work" - What exact behavior you observe, so you decide that it is not working? Does it prints "failed"? Or what? In the current state your problem is unclear.

Comment: module_name is always empty (even if I use "copy_from_user") but name_len always return value that is greater than 0

Comment: Please, update the question post with that information.

Comment: did it, any idea why coping from user space isn't working correctly? I even look in the source code of the original function and it still wont work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System call hooking example arguments are incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851520/system-call-hooking-example-arguments-are-incorrect)

Comment: i tried it with the di and bx register and it seems to fail do you know which register is needed to be used?

Comment: According to the [Linux System Call convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-and-user-space-f), on x86_64 the first syscall argument is passed via `rdi` register, and the second argument - via `rsi` register. You could also find useful an [example from lwn](https://lwn.net/Articles/750536/).